# Change Soft Keyboard layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

i would like to know how can i change the layout of the EditText and the "Done" button! Thanks!

PS. This Soft Keyboard has been changed to include Keys i need from the Sample provided by android sdk.

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating your own layout and showing it on Edittext instead.

Comment: I wanna use that one isnt that possible to change it somehow?

Comment: Creating Layout of your own is the option I am sure about. Regarding Changing the existing one I dont have idea about it.